# Group List by property then return only another property of this grouped objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have a list of Contracts and im bundling them together by clientId. But i want to return only the Contract ID.

```
Input => 
let c1 = {client:1,id:"c1"}
let c2 = {client:2,id:"c2"}
let c3 = {client:2,id:"c3"}
let c4 = {client:1,id:"c4"}
let c5 = {client:3,id:"c5"}
let list = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[c1.id,c4.id],[c2.id,c3.id],[c5.id]]
```

I have the following Function, but its returning two subgroups by its key (which is the only accessible thing i see so far)

```
 public JsonResult checkForSameClient(long[] listOfContracts)
    {


        IQueryable<ContratEspace> contrats = contratEspaceRepository.Get(1, listOfContracts.Count(), listOfContracts);
        var contratList = contrats.ToList();

        var finalArray = contrats.GroupBy(c => c.id_clientGestion).ToList();
            var answer = finalArray.Select(c=>c.Key).Distinct().ToList();

        return new JsonResult() { Data = answer };
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: this code is not bugged, is just not returning what i want.

Comment: you can use debugger to check that each step produces correct result, so narrow down the place which is producing the wrong data

Comment: Yes, the problem is that i am not sure im using the correct method to achieve what i want.

I have the list of contracts , then i group it by client_id. But instead of returning this list with sublists containing whole objects, i want a list with sublists containing only the Contract ID - not the whole contract.

Comment: So if the code is not returning what you want (i.e. not achieving desired result) then it is bugged.  Follow @Renat 's advice and use the debugger to step through this code and see what is going wrong

Comment: I understand - the problem is that i am learning c# syntax and i am not being able to achieve this result.
The problem rest in the Groupby() x Select() method - which is selecting the Key, when i want to actually access the contract ID . 
In my mind it would be something like this. 

var finalArray = contrats.GroupBy(c => c.id_clientGestion).Select(c=>c.id_contract).Distinct().ToList();

but this doesnt work. 
The intent of the question here is to know the correct method to use.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the Actual Output?  There is not enough here  to know why the code isn't working for you.  The methods you are using will work just fine if you use the proper data/fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GroupBy`, you get an `IGrouping`which consists of the `Key` of the group, and is also an `IEnumerable` of the members of the group. Since you just want the `id_contrat` from each member, you need to select that while preserving the groups.

```
var answer = contrats.GroupBy(c => c.id_clientGestion)
                     .Select(cg => cg.Select(c => c.id_contrat));
```

Answer (score 0):

public JsonResult checkForSameClient(long[] listOfContracts)
    {

I was able to Figure it out. 
I used the select Method and create a new Object just with the desired properties and then i group by it.

```
    IQueryable<ContratEspace> contrats = contratEspaceRepository.Get(1, listOfContracts.Count(), listOfContracts);
    var contratList = contrats.ToList();

        var answer = contrats.Select(i => new { i.id_contrat, i.id_clientGestion }).GroupBy(i=>i.id_clientGestion).ToList();

    return new JsonResult() { Data = answer };
}
```

Comment: this will gives you Array f Arrays of objects :``[[{id_contrat1,id_clientGestion1}],[{id_contrat2, id_clientGestion2}],[{id_contrat3,id_clientGestion3}]]`` not ``[[c1.id,c4.id],[c2.id,c3.id],[c5.id]]`` this is not output that you want

Comment: im still working on a way taking it from there - but its the closest i have so far.

Please let me know if you have another solution.

Thanks for the feedback! =)

Comment: in your ``Input`` you have this ``{client:1,id:"c1"}`` is that corresponds to ``{ i.id_contrat, i.id_clientGestion }``?

Comment: Don't use `ToList` every time you complete a step in LINQ - just chain the steps together.

Comment: for me it's like this : ``var finalArray = list.GroupBy(c => c.client).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.id));`` this will give you ``[[c1.id,c4.id],[c2.id,c3.id],[c5.id]]`` after serialization.